# Modification files by using R

Tags: r, simulation

I run 100 simulations into `R` by using some `R` codes to run them. Each simulation in a separate file which includes some another file (such as analyse, collect, etc. ) as my data is a big dataset.

After I run them I realized that there is a mistake in analyse file which I can not run them again into R. Because it takes 5 hours to done 100 simulations.

So, is there any way to modification the analyse for 100 files (100 simulations)? I mean that is there another code which can go through each file and copy new analyse (or replace the previous one with new one).

Here the code that I used:

```
filelist<-c("F:/analyse.R","F:/collect.R")

##Create 100 new folders - one for each simulated data set.
for (j in 1:100) {
  newdir <- paste0("F:/sim",j)
  dir.create(newdir)      # should test for error
  cwd <- getwd()          # CURRENT directory
  setwd(newdir)
  file.copy(filelist, newdir) ##This line should save the analyse, collect files in each folder.
  setwd(cwd)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure what the question is, could you clarify more?

Comment: Maybe `?tryCatch`?

Comment: `file.copy(filelist[1], newdir, overwrite = TRUE)` will replace the the `analyse.R` files in the directories. Also, try using `if(!dir.exists(newdir)) dir.create(newdir)` to create new directories only if they need creating.

Comment: if you want to read the R code and change your mistake, you could do `code <- readLines(filename)`, edit the code and then `writeLines(code, newfilename)` back to where you need it. And next time... don't write the same code 100 times in 100 files...